# MVC 5 DropDownList adding string to the value of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have to SelectList via DropDownListFor Html Helper in MVC like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProjectType, @Model.ProjectTypeList, "Select One",
                      new { @id = "ProjectTypeList" })
```

The thing is that in jQuery I write:

```
alert($('#ProjectType').val());
```

And it gives me the correct value. But if I write this (right after that):

```
var programmeUrl = '/api/Programme/' + $('#ProjectType').val()
```

I get something like this:

```
SomeValue%20?_=1409153033527
```

So my WebAPI returns Not found since it is only expecting SomeValue. Any ideas why am I getting this. It is frustrating since I do the same for others and don't have this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: `$('#ProjectType').find(":selected").text();`

Comment: Thanks wf4 but $('#ProjectType').find(":selected").text(); gives... the selected text. I need the selected value. It is frustrating since it works for all the combos except for this one.

Comment: my mistake, I take it this would not work either? `$('#ProjectType').find(":selected").val();`. Also, when you "view source" do you see the extra space in the `option`?

Comment: No. That is the error. Thanks a lot. :-) (I am tired and could not see that on my own. Thanks. :-) )

Comment: You're welcome - I have posted my comments as an answer so that you can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Cant see how `alert($('#ProjectType').val());` can work since you have changed the id attribute to `id="ProjectTypeList"`, so it should be  `alert($('#ProjectTypeList').val());`. And `$('#ProjectTypeList').find(":selected").val();` returns exactly the same value as `$('#ProjectTypeList').val());` so there is something else wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best not to use `.val()` on a select list because clicking an option doesn't change the value of the dropdown, it just adds the `:selected` property.

You should do it this way instead:

`$('#ProjectType').find(":selected").val();`